# Extract text from a NSString using regular expressions

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I have a NSString in this format:

"Key1-Value1,Key2-Value2,Key3-Value3,..."

I need only keys (with a space after every comma):

Key1, Key2, Key3, etc.

I thought to create an array of components from the string using the comma as separator, and after, for every component, extract all characters since the "-"; then I'd serialize the array elements. But I fear this could be very heavy about performances.

Do you know a way to do this using regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex will greatly depend on the data you are using. For example if the key or value is allowed to be all numbers, or allowed to contain space and punctuation, you would need to modify the regex. For your current example however this will work.

```
NSString *example = @"Key1-Value1,Key2-Value2,Key3-Value3,...";
NSString *result = [example stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\\w+)-(\\w+),?" 
                                                      withString:@"$1, " 
                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [example length])];
result = [result stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@", "]];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Both keys and values may contain letters, numbers, spaces and punctuation (except comma), for example: "Storia; Storia dell'Arte" is a valid key.

Comment: Well then it gets more complicated, if the rule is they must be contained within quotes that is not too difficult, but if the quotes can contain escaped quotes it becomes more difficult :)

Comment: I can ask my working partner to generate keys and values inside quotes.

Comment: If you can work on the original format then you probably should try and get the keys and values already separated, such as in a XML file.

Comment: Yes, originally I thought at a plist file, but unfortunately my partner made ​​it clear that I can not ask so much... However, is it possible to use your code to handle strings like this: "Key1"-"Value1","Key2"-"Value2",...?